# Refactor void method to be testable

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring, mstest

Consider I have Class1, this class has one method to decide about the type that input object should be convert to. What I want to do is to write some unit tests to make sure this functionality. I don’t want to test TypeAConvertor method or TypeBConvertor method. I want to test CheckAndStore method about correct decision. Now return type of this method is void. So I can’t access the object that is converted.Whenever CheckAndStore method is called, in one array inputs can have different states, but 99% have the same state

```
    public class Class1
    {
    public void CheckAndStore(Input[] inputs)
    {

            foreach (var input in inputs)
            {

                if (input.State==1)
                {
                    TypeA result = TypeAConvertor.Convert(input);
                  //Store in TypeA mongo collection
                }
                else if (input.State==2)

                {
                    TypeB result = TypeBConvertor.Convert(input);
                //Store in TypeB mongo collection

                }
            //other conditions
            }



    }

}
```

I need to refactor this method to be testable what I’m thinking about is to return an object with two properties of IList and IList and add results one by one to these two lists, but I think it’s not efficient because in 99% I initialize unused and empty list. Is anyone has a better solution to refactor this?

Comment: Going to need more details about that method under test. The comments mention mongo collections. I think you may be focusing on the wrong subject but without knowing more about the collection situation I am not sure.

Comment: I'd create an interface for TypeAConvertor and the other one, inject mocks through constructor and see which ones Convert method was called. Cleanest test would use single element Input[] for all scenarios that you expect to get clean and readible assertions.

Comment: @yoger, thanks, your solution solved my issue